# ILazyInitProxy ClassNotFoundException in Wicket Websocket

Tags: java, dependency-injection, websocket, wicket, classnotfound

The following error often shows up when a websocket connection is opened or closed in my wicket web application:

```
    2016-07-11 10:53:07,874 ERROR [::] [qtp1484594489-42303] [] [||] - org.apache.wicket.protocol.ws.api.AbstractWebSocketProcessor - An error occurred during processing of a WebSocket message
net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:256)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:286)
    at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory.createProxy(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:191)
    at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$ProxyReplacement.readResolve(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:270)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7815.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7812.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer.deserialize(JavaSerializer.java:122)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AbstractPageStore.deserializePage(AbstractPageStore.java:152)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AbstractCachingPageStore.getPage(AbstractCachingPageStore.java:67)
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PageStoreManager$SessionEntry.getPage(PageStoreManager.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PageStoreManager$PersistentRequestAdapter.getPage(PageStoreManager.java:357)
    at org.apache.wicket.page.AbstractPageManager.getPage(AbstractPageManager.java:82)
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PageManagerDecorator.getPage(PageManagerDecorator.java:50)
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer$2.getPage(PageAccessSynchronizer.java:246)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.ws.api.AbstractWebSocketProcessor.getPage(AbstractWebSocketProcessor.java:315)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.ws.api.AbstractWebSocketProcessor.broadcastMessage(AbstractWebSocketProcessor.java:243)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.ws.api.AbstractWebSocketProcessor.onClose(AbstractWebSocketProcessor.java:182)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.ws.jetty.JettyWebSocketProcessor$JettyWebSocket.onClose(JettyWebSocketProcessor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.closeIn(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.handle(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:395)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:237)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wicket/proxy/ILazyInitProxy
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.proxy.ILazyInitProxy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 66 more
```

The *AbstractWebSocketProcessor* class tries to broadcast a message to notify listeners that the websocket closes.
In doing this, it tries to load a wicket page. That page contains multiple autowired fields and it needs to be deserialized, but that's where the classnotfoundexception of the proxy class occurs.

I suspect this issue to be the cause of a thread leak, but I can not reproduce the error consistently.

How could this error occur?

Comment: Is wicket-ioc in the classpath ? Check whether there are more than one versions of it in the classpath.

Comment: I used mvn dependency tree to verify, only wicket-ioc version 7.2.0 is referred in the whole project

Comment: Unless there are some tricks with the ClassLoaders (Wicket doesn't do any!) I don't see why the class cannot be found.